# How to properly inject dependencies into Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, dependency-injection

I'm writing my first Flask app. So far, I've gotten everything to work by doing this (note that this code would be spread across multiple files):

```
class AppDefinition:

    def __init__(self):
        self.App = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config = True)
        self.PlacesProvider = GooglePlacesSearchProvider(
            'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json',
            'my_api_key')

app = AppDefinition()

@app.App.route('/search/phone/<phone>/<language>')
def search_with_phone_number(phone: str, language: str):
    resp = app.PlacesProvider.get_by_phone_number(phone, language)
    return from_response(resp)

@app.App.route('/search/address/<address>/<language>')
def search_with_address(address: str, language: str):
    resp = app.PlacesProvider.get_by_address(address, language)
    return from_response(resp)

def from_response(resp: Response):
    return json.dumps(resp.json(), ensure_ascii = False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = 5000
    app.App.run(HOST, PORT)
```

However, I'm not particularly happy with this code. The controller methods haven't been encapsulated into a proper class, the dependencies aren't injected properly and there doesn't appear to be a way to encapsulate the controller methods. All these issues seem to concern dependency injection at their core so that's probably the real problem here, IMHO. Given that, how would I go about doing dependency injection in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Dependency Injector](https://github.com/ets-labs/python-dependency-injector). Here is how you application will look like.

Listing of `application.py`:

```
import json

from dependency_injector import containers, providers
from dependency_injector.ext import flask
from flask import Flask


# Services

class Response:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def json(self):
        return self.data


class GooglePlacesSearchProvider:

    def __init__(self, url, api_key):
        ...

    def get_by_phone_number(self, phone, language):
        return Response({'result': 'phone-number-lookup-result'})

    def get_by_address(self, phone, language):
        return Response({'result': 'address-lookup-result'})


# Views

def search_with_phone_number(phone: str, language: str, places_provider: GooglePlacesSearchProvider):
    resp = places_provider.get_by_phone_number(phone, language)
    return from_response(resp)


def search_with_address(address: str, language: str, places_provider: GooglePlacesSearchProvider):
    resp = places_provider.get_by_address(address, language)
    return from_response(resp)


def from_response(resp: Response):
    return json.dumps(resp.json(), ensure_ascii=False)


# Container

class ApplicationContainer(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    """Application container."""

    app = flask.Application(Flask, __name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    config = providers.Configuration()

    places_provider = providers.Factory(
        GooglePlacesSearchProvider,
        config.services.places.url,
        config.services.places.api_key,
    )

    search_with_phone_number_view = flask.View(
        search_with_phone_number,
        places_provider=places_provider,
    )

    search_with_address_view = flask.View(
        search_with_address,
        places_provider=places_provider,
    )


# Application factory

def create_app():
    container = ApplicationContainer()
    container.config.from_yaml('config.yml')
    container.config.services.places.api_key.from_env('PLACES_API_KEY')

    app = container.app()
    app.container = container

    app.add_url_rule(
        '/search/phone/<phone>/<language>',
        view_func=container.search_with_phone_number_view.as_view(),
    )
    app.add_url_rule(
        '/search/address/<address>/<language>',
        view_func=container.search_with_address_view.as_view(),
    )

    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = 5000
    app = create_app()
    app.run(HOST, PORT)
```

Listing of `config.yml`:

```
services:
  places:
    url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json"
```

And you will need to provide API key as an environment variable when run the app:

```
PLACES_API_KEY=key python -m application
```

I recommend to split this to multiple files. Take a look at Dependency Injector [Flask tutorial](http://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/tutorials/flask.html).

Comment: @Yunnosch, thanks for the review. Edited. What do you think?

Comment: :-) Looks like an explained full answer now. Please understand that I lack the actual technical understanding to judge whether it is an upvotably helpful and correct answer. But it definitly is an answer now.

Comment: Got it, thank you, no problems. Btw, I completely agree and understand the concern you had. I hurried up. My initial answer wasn't too useful. I enjoy that people like you watching the community. I will keep following and spreading this culture.

Comment: Wow, perfect. Anything and more than I could have hoped for.